# App to app communication in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

So I want to send a message programmatically from one windows phone app to another. It just has to be a text message, but I want to push messages from one app to another on the same phone.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Edit: Btw these apps needs to be able to run offline

Comment: Your options are covered well by this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-10-App-to-App-Communication-in-Windows-Phone-8

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/.
You can use the trial to study.
Good manual: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/08/22/push-notifications-made-easy-using-windows-azure-notification-hubs-with-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: The question asked for app to app on the same phone. And, offline. So, Azure isn't a good match for the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work offline, the best you can do is registering a custom URI scheme, and use it to launch one app from the other, passing your message along.